Object became null in @CachePut annotation
For some reason I can see that object was passed not null, but in key expression it is null already.
I am trying to read some data from DB and add it to the cache.
Here are my methods.
public void preloadCache() {
        List<Statistic> allData = repository.findAll();
        log.info("Data found {}", allData.size());
        allData.forEach(cacheService::populateQuarterStatisticCache);
}

It calls separate service
@Service
@Slf4j
public class CacheService {

    @CachePut(value = "quarterStatistic", key = "#statistic.type + '-' + #statistic.location")
    public QuarterBusinessesStatistic populateQuarterStatisticCache(Statistic statistic) {
        log.info("Loading statistic into cache: {}-{}", statistic.getType(), statistic.getLocation());
        return statistic.getData();
    }
}

Logs shows me that there is one object and it is not null
[nio-8080-exec-1] StatisticClient     : Data found 1
[nio-8080-exec-1] CacheService     : Preloading statistic into cache: restaurant-New York

But next line of the log tells me
SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'type' cannot be found on null
If I am changing key in my @CachePut annotation to key = "#statistic?.type + '-' + #statistic?.location" there will be no exceptions. But in the cache I will see stored object by null-null key
I can debug it and see that my object is not null. Logs also prove that. But in key expression it is null for some reason.
Does anybody had the same?
Note: I tried to change key to something like
#statistic.getType() + '-' + #statistic.getLocation() - same result
My pom.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>3.3.5</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Did you by any chance override the compiler plugin in maven? Which Spring Boot version are you using? Please add your full pom.xml.

Try using #a0 instead of #statistic to see if it works. If it does you wrongly configured (or wrongly overriden) the maven compiler plugin.

@M.Deinum #a0 works. Added pom.xml
Also I noticed that it works only if my preloadCache method is called from another method. But if it is triggered as @PostConstruct - @CachePut looks like totally ignored.

If #a0 works you have configured/overrridden the compiler in yuor maven build. Looking at your pom.xml just remove the maven-compiler-plugin the spring boot parent already configures it properly for use with named parameters. Don't use @PostConstruct for these initializations as those are most like to be executed too early, use an ApplicationRunner which will run after the application has been fully setup and everything is in place.

yes, removing plugin and adding
<maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
helped. Thank you @M.Deinum.
Do you think I can use any spring context events instead of ApplicationRunner?

You don't need maven.compiler.source just leave java.version that is what Spring Boot is using to set the version. Please use the setup as it is intended don't work around it. You can use an ApplicationListener with ContextRefreshedEvent but an ApplicationRunner is far easier. Just create an @Bean method that takes your repository, use lambda to implement it and call the methods you need.

Ignore that, you aren't using Spring Boot as a parent (which is recommended actually) but rather as a BOM. Then use maven.compiler.release instead.

@M.Deinum Thank you for your answers. Switched to parent option.

From the comments it is apparent that positional parameters, #a0 do work and named parameters #statistic fails. This is an indication that your maven-compiler-plugin isn't setup properly.
From your pom.xml your maven-compiler-plugin is configured as follows:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Now with Spring Boot 3 (or rather Spring Framework 6.1) is is needed to enable compilation with parameter name retention. You need to configure this in your maven-compiler-plugin.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>${java.version}</release>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

This will keep the parameter names in the class file and will make #statistic work.
An easier way is, as you are using Spring Boot, is to remove this maven-compiler-plugin al together and use the spring-boot-starter-parent which does all of this (and more) already.
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.5</version>
</parent>

